# How to uprade from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS without internet connection ?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, offline

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and want to update to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but do not have an internet connection or another Ubuntu PC. I don't have an internet connection as the network modem drivers only works on windows and mac OS X. Can i just update it by putting it on usb and then onto the Ubuntu PC?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, the update from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will be officially available at July 24th.

And because you haven't internet connection, the only way is to use the Ubuntu 14.04 DVD.